# FizzBuzz: num%15 being first versus num%3 being first

Tags: javascript, fizzbuzz

I just want to know why 'FizzBuzz only works when num % 15 === 0 is first as opposed to when num % 3 === 0 is first.

For example:

```
for (let num = 1; num <= 100; num++) {
if (num % 15 === 0) {
    console.log('FizzBuzz');
} else if (num % 5 === 0) {
    console.log('Buzz')
} else if (num % 3 === 0) {
    console.log('Fizz');
} else {
    console.log(num);
}
```

}

vs.

```
for (let num = 1; num <= 100; num++) {
if (num % 3 === 0) {
    console.log('Fizz');
} else if (num % 5 === 0) {
    console.log('Buzz')
} else if (num % 15 === 0) {
    console.log('FizzBuzz');
} else {
    console.log(num);
}
```

}

Comment: Step through in a debugger to see *exactly* what happens in this code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`else if` basically means "If the previous condition didn't pass THEN IF...". So, in your second snippet, if `num % 3 === 0` is true, it will never bother checking if `num % 5 === 0` or `num % 15 === 0`.